# Indexing Nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, object, indexing

It feels like a question which has already been asked but I have not been able to find an answer to this.

Say I have a JSON file like this:

```
    {
        "material": {
            "name": "material",
            "nav": [
              {
                "text": "Backgrounds",
                "url": "backgrounds"
              },
              {
                "text": "Templates",
                "url": "templates"
              }
            ],
            "methods": [{
                "index":[{
                    "title": "Material",
                    "description": "Bla",
                    "keywords": [ "website material", "sozai", "素材" ]
                }],
                "backgrounds":[{
                    "title": "Backgrounds",
                    "description": "Bla.",
                    "keywords": [ "website backgrounds", "tiled backgrounds"]
                }]
            }]
        }
   }
```

And I json_decode it

```
$pages = json_decode($data);
```

To access, say, material > methods > index > title, I could do

```
$pages->material->methods[0]->index[0]->title
```

And that is fine (or is it?)

But this would not work with variables mixed in.
Elsewhere I get the method name ($method, which will be "index") and put it in place of index.

```
$pages->material->methods[0]->$method[0]->title
```

This results in a "Undefined property: stdClass::$i"

I am aware that I can break this problem up into more lines storing the array in a new variable then indexing from there, but that is what I am trying to find the alternative to.

I would like to know if there is a more intuitive way to index this (without the [0]?) without going outside that one expression.

Comment: `$pages->material->methods[0]->{$method}[0]->title`?

Comment: Pass `true` to the second parameter of [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php) to force it to be an associative array. Then you can use your variable, eg `$pages['material']['methods'][0][$method][0]['title']`

Comment: @Cyclone and Phil Thank you for your comments, those two ways would both work. I still felt like I was doing something wrong because of the [0]s - but it looks like I'm just thinking too much into it.

Answer (score 2):

If `$method` is `index`, `$method[0]` is the first character of the string, `i`.

A simple:

```
$pages->material->methods[0]->$method->title
```

or

```
$pages->material->methods[0]->{$method}->title
```

(slightly clearer to read, IMO) should suffice.

Comment: The proposed code does not work since index (or $method) is an array and not an object - but I will use the { } way to separate the variable from the expression.

Comment: @tonytony I was going off the statement `$method, which will be "index"`. Adjust as necessary if it's an array.